# Mesilat Yesharim - how much time per day for zehirut/watchfulness

Tags: time, mussar-ethics, ramchal

The Mesilat Yesharim brings down zehirut (watchfulness) as one of the first steps to master.

Zehirut in essence means working on cleaning oneself up from all bad behavior through analyzing one's daily actions.

How much time per day is one supposed to devote to this practice, and how much detail should he look into his actions?

(If anyone also has tips/experience in how to work on this please comment. biggest problem i have with it is getting stuck in some area.)

Comment: Wouldn't this be different per person?

Comment: @DoubleAA so let's say for an average person

Answer (score 3):

The Zohar recommends examining one's deeds and repenting every night before going to sleep ([*Korach* 178a](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%92_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%97_%D7%90)):

> הא אוקמו דבכל לילא ולילא, עד לא ישכב ועד לא נאים בעי בר נש למיעבד חושבנא מעובדוי דעבד כל ההוא יומא ויתב מנייהי ויבעי עלייהו רחמי

This is cited approvingly by poskim such as the Mateh Moshe ([*Amud Ha'avoda* §829](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40439&st=&pgnum=282)):

> יעשה כדעת הזוהר וישב קודם שישכב ויתאונן גבר חי על חטאיו ויפשפש במעשיו ואם ימצא ישוב בתשובה שלימה

As mentioned in [DoubleAA's comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/mesilat-yesharim-how-much-time-per-day-for-zehirut-watchfulness#comment85002_33416), the amount of time spent should depend on the individual, although a person should probably not spend so much time that it would disrupt his ability to live a balanced life (see Rambam, [*Hil. Dei'os* 1:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=2&perek=1&halocha=7), הדרך הבינונית שאנו חייבין ללכת בה נקראת דרך זו דרך ה; regarding going to extremes as a temporary measure, see ibid. 2:2).

The Vilna Gaon encouraged the contemplation of fear of Heaven before and after Torah study (see [*Even Sh'leima* 1:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14216&st=&pgnum=22)):

> צריך לפנות לבו בכל יום קודם הלימוד ואחריו מעיפוש הדיעות והמדות ביראת חטא ומע״ט

The gemara ([*Shabbos* 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=31&format=text)), discussing the need for Torah study (and other laudable pursuits) to be accompanied by fear of Heaven, draws a comparison to mixing one part of preservative into 180 parts of grain. According to R' Chaim Volozhiner ([*Ru'ach Chayim* 1:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14555&st=&pgnum=8)), one may infer that a person should preface his Torah study with a proportionate rather than excessive amount of time devoted to introspection and contemplation:

> עכ"פ התורה היא העיקר ובכור תורה די קב יראה, והוא ערך חלק ק"פ. ולערך בט"ו שעות תורה די בה' מינוטין יראה, רק שתקדם היראה לתורה שקודם לתורה יהרהר ביראת ה' כדי שתהא יראת חטאו קודם לחכמתו ותתקיים חכמתו, כענין שא' ערבת קב חומטין כו' מוטב שלא העלית, אף כי ירצה עתה ליתן קביים חומטין מ"מ מוטב שלא העלית

Comment: If you're up 16 hours a day, that's 5 minutes and 6 chalakim or introspection.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yup. Torah study itself is imbued with properties conducive to *yir'as HaShem*, so I sort of think of those couple of minutes as a jump start to properly orient one's mind while learning (and from there the learning itself continues to sustain the *yiras HaShem*).

Comment: I heard that a non-Chossid (IIRC it was R' Chaim Volozhiner or one of his talmidim) came to the Alter Rebbe and asked him why Chassidim learn Chassidus for such a long time? The Alter Rebbe quoted the Gemara, to which the misnaged answered like DoubleAA. The Alter Rebbe answered that it's the mixing that takes a long time

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Cute. So they had different ideas as to which element of the *mashal* provides guidance on the appropriate amount time to spend.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, Fred How does the mashal provide any guidance how long to spend on mixing? (Also, did the misnaged in the story answer in _chalakim_? :) )

Comment: @DoubleAA If applying preservative is an extensive process one might conclude that studying should be preceded with similarly extensive preparation. As far as chalakim, I didn't realize there was another way to measure time. :) 180 does divide 1080 nicely, though.

Comment: Fred Ok, but I have no idea how long it takes to mix in a preservative at that ratio and volume. Do you? Isn't it probably variable based on the kind of preservative? If that detail was essential to the mashal, why was it left out? @ShmuelBrin ping

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point. I don't know how long it actually takes, but assuming (for argument's sake) that it was well understood back then that it generally took a long time, then it wouldn't be as exigent to include that detail.

Comment: @DoubleAA Found the source (R' Chaim of Volozhin) and edited it in: "Torah is the essence, and one *kav* of *yir'ah* is sufficient for one *kor* of Torah, and this is a ratio of 1:180. And measuring according to 15 hours of Torah study, 5 minutes of *yir'ah* is sufficient, so long as the *yir'ah* precedes the Torah..."

Comment: @Fred He only learned 15 hours a day?! Feh!

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess someone of your stature requires an extra 20 seconds of *yir'ah* a day. :) Actually, he may have been going according to the standard of people learning in Volozhin judging from what I've heard of the schedule there.