# How much time should one spend on learning Torah a day

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study

If one is awake sixteen out of 24 hours a day , how much should he learn out of those hours. Sources are appreciated .

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31135/759

Comment: see the shulchan aruch harav on talmud torah. basically - the more the better

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33416

Comment: I believe the canonical answer is "16 hours, minus the time spent on other mitzvot"

Comment: ...But, that said, I'm not sure by what token you're allowed a full 8 hours of sleep

Answer (score 2):

R Eliezer Melamed (R*osh Yeshiva in Har Bracha and the author of the Pninei Halacha series of books on halacha*) was recently asked the question of **how many hours one should learn on shabbat**.

He brings many sources showing shabbat should be half for oneself/family, half to learn and pray. **He therefore concludes the obligation is to learn six hours on shabbat** (25 hours of shabbat; subtract 7 hours of sleep, remains 18 awake; half for prayer and learning is 9 hours; subtract 3 hours of prayer, remains six for learning).

See the [full text of his response](http://www.torahmusings.com/2015/11/a-minimum-of-six-hours/).

Answer (score 2):

*How much time should one spend on learning Torah a day?*
**as much as possible**. For what is considered possible see below (no time can be used for being idle (unless you are old and can not concentrate) or for idle talk)

Summary of the Hilchos Talmud Torah of the Rav quoted below regarding the law of time for torah (to see more sources please see the footnotes on the link below)

Is

2. ...**biblically (see 4. below) you are obligated to set a large amount of time for learning Torah every day, i.e. at least half a day, do not work for more then half of it, the Torah should be made chief and your work secondary**...
3. someone that wants to do this commandment the right way should work the minimum just to support the life himself and his family (no pleasures), (he should not worry about his wife and children more than his life.)...
4. all this is for a talmid chochom or someone that can become a talmid chochom,
   but **someone** **that did not get to that level ** that he can learn the reasons of the laws and their sources... even if he makes his Torah (learning) primary since he is short-minded and is called a bur, as it is learnt on the posuk "one man out of a thousand I found": (rashi [Kohelet 7.28](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16468#showrashi=true)) It is customary in the world that [out of] a thousand who enter [a school] to learn Scripture, only one hundred emerge from it to succeed to be fit for Mishnah, and [of] those hundred who enter to [learn] Mishnah, only ten emerge from them to [learn] Gemara...

   he is not obligated not to have pleasures, and to make his work secondary to learn something that he does not understand completely

   but legally **it is enough for him to set a time for learning by day and night (see 5. below)**
   ...
   and the rest of the day be **busy** with **busi**ness so that he can strengthen the hands of the talmidai chachomim that learn day and night..., it will be considered as though he himself learned them as the Chachomim explain the posuk Devorim 33.18  "Rejoice, Zebulun, in your departure, and Issachar, in your tents"
   and he can support his children a little more widely (more then just to live) for his sons to be able to learn Torah as it is needed and for his daughters to be educated in the straight path (as is explained in the laws of charity)

If business is not so good and he is unable to fulfill his set time by day and/or by night, he can just learn one chapter by day and one chapter by night, if his business is VERY tight that he can not even do one chapter he can fulfill his obligation by reading the shma by day and night  
this can also be done by someone that can (be a talmid chochom) learn... if he needs to work all day
the same applied to an old man who does not have the energy to learn all day...

5. all this was if he worked himself, but **if** others work for him (**he is not busy working**), or his livelihood comes from tsedoko of the congregation, **he needs to learn day and night and does not fulfill his obligation by learning only a set time by day and a set time by night**
   but **idle talk is forbidden**...
   even a poor man that collects from doors is obligated to learn torah the rest of the day and knight
6. even someone that works himself is forbidden to idle talk (he is only permitted to spend his free time on his livelihood) and any time he is not working he is responsible to learn Torah

see [chapter 4](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/4/index.htm) regarding using time for prayer and other mitzvois

[הלכות תלמוד תורה > הלכות ת"ת פרק שלישי](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/3/index.htm)

> ב
>   ...
>   וחייב הוא מן התורה לקבוע לו עת גדולה לתלמוד תורה בכל יום כמו חצי היום לפחות מלבד לימוד הלילהלה ולא יעסוק במלאכה כל היום או רובו שנאמרלו ודברת בם והלא כבר נאמר ושננתם ומה תלמוד לומר ודברת בם שלא יהא כל דיבורך אלא בם כלומר שתעשם עיקר ולא טפלהלט ועל כןמ חייב לעשות תורתו קבעמא ומלאכתו עראי
>   ...
>
> ג ולכן מי שנשאו לבו לקיים מצוה זו כראוי יעשה מלאכה בכל יום מעט כדי חייו בלבד ויסיר התאוות ותענוגי הזמן מלבו כמו שאמרו חכמים כך היא דרכה של תורה פת במלח תאכל ומים במשורה תשתה ועל הארץ תישן וחיי צער תחיה ובתורה אתה עמל ואין לו לחוס על נפש אשתו ובניו יותר מעל חיי נפשו שהם בצער ולזה ודאי תספיק לו מלאכת עראי בישועת ה' והצלחתו בלי הזכרת מעשה נסים.
>
> ולכן אמרו חכמים שהלל מחייב את העניים בדין שמים על שמבטלים מצות תלמוד תורה מחמת טרדתם במזונותיהם כל היום או רובו אין עושין כהלל שהיה חוטב עצים בכל יום ומשתכר חצי דינר והיה נותן חציו לשומר בית המדרש שהיה בשדה בימיהם ומחציו היתה פרנסתו ופרנסת אנשי ביתו דהיינו ג' פונדיונות ובכל פונדיון היה ניקח בימיהם לחם כשש בצים ומזה היה מוציא גם שאר הוצאות ביתו וגם לשבתות וימים טוביםואף שאין כל אדם יכול לעשות כן ממש כהלל מכל מקום דנין על שלא רצה לעשות כעין מעשה הלל לחיות חיי צער.
>
> וגם מי שלמד כבר כל התורה קודם שנשא והוליד וזוכרה היטב חייב לעשות תורתו קבע לחזור על הראשונות ולהעמיק בעיון ולסבור ולהבין דבר מתוך דבר כפי יכלתו ומלאכתו עראי כמו שקבלו חכמים בפירוש הפסוק ודברת בם:
>
> ד וכל זה בתלמיד חכם שלמד או שדעתו יפה ומצליח בתלמודו ויוכל להיות תלמיד חכם ללמוד כל התורה שבעל פה מהתלמוד והפוסקים כמו הרא"ש וב"י.
>
> אבל מי שלא הגיע למדה זו שיוכל ללמוד טעמי ההלכות ומקורן ואפילו בלימוד המביא לידי מעשה לבדו רק הלכות פסוקות לבדן אף אם יעשה תורתו קבע מחמת קוצר דעתו ונקרא בור וכמו שאמרו על פסוק אדם אחד מאלף מצאתי אלף נכנסים למקרא יוצאים מהם מאה מאה נכנסים למשנה כו' אינו חייב לחיות חיי צער ולעשות מלאכתו עראי כדי להרבות בלימוד שאינו מבין על בוריו שהוא לימוד ההלכות בלי טעמים כמו שנתבאר למעלה וגם עתיד לשכחו אלא אם כן עושה במדת חסידות ואהבת התורה.
>
> אבל מן הדין יוצא ידי חובתו בקביעות עתים לתלמוד תורה לקיים מה שכתוב והגית בו יומם ולילה בקביעות עתים ביום ובלילה בכדי ללמוד ולזכור היטב לימוד המביא לידי מעשה בלבד שהוא חובה על הכל דהיינו השולחן ערוך מהלכות הצריכות לכל אדם לידע אותן בלי שאלת חכם ולימוד בהגדות ומדרשים או ספרי מוסר שנבנו על מדרשי חכמים שדבריהם תורה וקבלה ולא שכל אנושי כמו שנתבאר למעלה.
>
> ושאר כל היום יעסוק במשא ומתן כדי שיוכל להחזיק ידי תלמידי חכמים שהם לומדי התורה יום ולילה עד שיודעים הלכותיה בטעמיהן על בוריין ויהא נחשב לו כאלו למד כן ממש בעצמו ותורתם נקראת על שמו כמו שפירשו חכמים בפסוק שמח זבולון בצאתך ויששכר באהליך וגם יוכל למלאות מחסורי בניו ובנותיו בהרחבה קצת כדי שיוכלו בניו לעסוק בתורה כראוי ולהדריך בנותיו בדרך ישרה כמו שיתבאר בהלכות צדקה.
>
> ואם אירע לפעמים גודל טרדה במשא ומתן עד שלא יוכל ללמוד כל העת הקבוע לו ביום וכן בלילה יוכל לצאת ידי חובת מצות והגית בו יומם ולילה אפילו בלימוד מועט כמו פרק אחד ביום וכן פרק אחד בלילה ובשעת הדחק שהטירדה גדולה יותר מדאי ואין לו פנאי אפילו פרק אחד יוכל לצאת ידי חובתו בקריאת שמע שחרית וערבית לקיים מצות והגית בו יומם ולילה ביום ההוא שהוא שעת הדחק ואי אפשר בענין אחר.
>
> וכן אפילו מי שדעתו יפה ויוכל ללמוד טעמי ההלכות מהתלמוד שצריך לעשות תורתו קבע ומלאכתו עראי אם אירע לו לפעמים שצריך להתעסק במלאכתו ופרנסתו כל היום כולו ואי אפשר לו ליפנות ממנה כלל בלי הפסד יקיים גם כן מצות והגית בו יומם ולילה בפרק אחד שחרית ופרק אחד ערבית ובשעת הדחק מאד שגם זה אי אפשר לו יוכל לצאת ידי חובתו בקריאת שמע שחרית וערבית.
>
> וכן מי שהוא בעל יסורים או שהוא זקן מופלג שתשש כחו ואינו יכול לעסוק תמיד בתורה חייב לקבוע לו עתים לתלמוד תורה ביום ובלילה כפי כחו ויכלתו ואם אינו יכול לקבוע עתים גדולים יוכל לצאת ידי חובתו בפרק אחד שחרית ופרק אחד ערבית:
>
> ה וכל זה במתפרנס ממעשה ידיו ממש אבל אם מלאכתו נעשית על ידי אחרים וכן המתפרנס מהצדקה של קהל או יחידים חייב לעסוק בתורה יומם ולילה ממש בכל ענין ואינו יוצא ידי חובתו כלל מן התורה בקביעות עתים גם אם דעתו קצרה ללמוד טעמי ההלכות שהרי נאמר בתורה סתם על כל אדם מישראל ודברת בם בשבתך בביתך ובלכתך בדרך וגו' ופירשו חכמים לעשותם קבע ועיקר ומלאכתו עראי כשצריך למעשה ידיו אבל דברים בטלים כלל כלל לא ואם שח עובר בעשה שנאמר ודברת בם ולא בדברים בטלים וזה שקובע עתים לתורה דרשו עליו חכמים שהוא מיפר תורה כמ"ש עת לעשות לה' הפרו תורתיך.
>
> ואפילו עני המחזר על הפתחים חייב לעסוק בתורה שאר כל היום וכל הלילה:
>
> ו וגם המתפרנס ממעשה ידיו ואפילו תורתו עראי בקביעות עתים לא הותר לו מן התורה אלא לעסוק בעסקיו שהם צרכי פרנסתו ומשא ומתן ממה שאמרה תורה ואספת דגנך אבל לא בדברים בטלים לגמרי בין לדבר בין לשמוע כי בכל עת שאינו עוסק בפרנסתו חייב לעסוק בתורה בכל עת שאפשר...

Answer (score 1):

Likutei Amarim (Tanya) Chapter 25

> אלא שלמטה הוא תחת הזמן ובאותה שעה לבדה שעוסק בה בתור' או במצוה כי אח"כ אם עוסק בדבר אחר נפרד מהיחוד העליון למטה. והיינו כשעוסק בדברים בטלים לגמרי שאין בהם צורך כלל לעבודת ה' ואעפ"כ כשחוזר ושב לעבודת ה' אח"כ לתורה ולתפלה ומבקש מחילה מה' על שהיה אפשר לו לעסוק אז בתורה ולא עסק ה' יסלח לו כמארז"ל עבר על מצות עשה ושב לא זז משם עד שמוחלין לו. ולזה תקנו ברכת סלח לנו שלש פעמים בכל יום על עון ביטול תורה שאין אדם ניצול ממנו בכל יום וכמו התמיד שהיה מכפר על מצות עשה. ואין זה אחטא ואשוב אא"כ שבשעת החטא ממש הוא סומך על התשובה ולכך חוטא כמ"ש במ"א:
>   However, here below, [the union] is within the limits of time, persisting only during such time when one is occupied in the study of Torah,, or in the performance of a commandment. For afterwards, if he engages in anything else, he is here below separated from the Higher Unity. This is so when he occupies himself with altogether vain things which are utterly useless for the Divine Service. Nevertheless, should he later repent and return to the service of G-d, to Torah and prayer, and ask forgiveness of G-d for not having engaged in the Torah when he could have done so, G-d will pardon him. To quote the Rabbis: "If one has transgressed against a positive precept, but has repented, he is pardoned on the spot." Therefore they instituted the blessing of "Forgive us" to be recited three times daily for the sin of neglecting the Torah, a sin which no one can escape each day. Similarly the daily burnt-offering used to bring atonement for neglect of the positive precepts. This is not the same as saying, "I will sin and repent afterwards," unless at the time he is committing the sin he relies on subsequent repentance and sins because of it, as explained elsewhere.

In short, if you're not doing something else that will help you with the service of G-d, you need to be learning Torah.